My ajax post request doesn't work in my ASP.NET MVC project
I'm trying to make a request to controller but it doesn't work. The first console.log() shows the correct id, so I think I passed it right in the html button. The id parameter is always 0 when it arrives at the controller.
That is the view's code:
function Delete(id) {
    console.log(id)

    if (!confirm("Vai excluir o produto mesmo chefe?")) {
        return;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Produtos/Delete",
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType:"json",
        data: JSON.stringify({id : id}),
        success: function(response){
            alert(response.message)
        },
        error: function(error){
            alert(error.message)
        }
    });
}

This is the controller method:
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(int id)
{
    var produto =  _produtosRepository.GetById(id);

    if (produto == null)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = $"Erro ao remover produto de id = {id}." });
    }
    
    _produtosRepository.Delete(produto);
    _produtosRepository.Save();

    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Produto deletado com sucesso." });
}

I tried to change the $.ajax call to fetch, but it doesn't work either. I don't know what do, could someone help me?
PS: I'm new to the ASP.NET MVC world, so I'm probably making a ridiculous mistake.

By default, the Id parameter in the controller action for ASP.NET MVC/API is treated as a route path.
You don't need to send the id as the request body. Instead, provide it in the route.
$.ajax({
  url: `/Produtos/Delete/${id}`,
  method: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response){
    alert(response.message)
  },
  error: function(error){
    alert(error.message)
  }
});


The server-side Delete(int id) method expects a parameter named id, but the client-side code sends a JSON object { id: id }. ASP.NET Core's default model binder may not correctly map this JSON object to the method parameter because it expects form-urlencoded or query string data for simple parameters.
Use [FromBody] on the id parameter. This tells ASP.NET Core to bind the parameter from the JSON body of the request.
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete([FromBody] int id)
{
    var produto = _produtosRepository.GetById(id);

    if (produto == null)
    {
        return Json(new { success = false, message = $"Erro ao remover produto de id = {id}." });
    }

    _produtosRepository.Delete(produto);
    _produtosRepository.Save();

    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Produto deletado com sucesso." });
}

If [FromBody] is not used, ASP.NET Core's model binder won't know how to extract the id from the JSON body, resulting in the default value 0.
